Why are my Open Graph Meta Tags being ignored
For this HTML page it has the following meta tags:
<meta property="og:title" content="Matthews MD For 64 HD">
<meta property="og:type" content="organization">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://louishoweproduction.blob.core.windows.net/organizations/MatthewsMDColorado/Mark%20Circle%20Photo_73.png">
<meta property="og:description" content="Mark Matthews, who spent four decades ... lots of text">

opengraph.xyz recognizes the tags. But when I go in Twitter to email or text that page, it does not use the metatags and instead just places the url as the content.
What am I missing? And I know I haven't done the Twitter, LinkedIn, etc. specific tags. But I figure they should all fallback to these standard ones.

When I view the raw source, I can't see your tags, but I can see them when I inspect the code via my console.  As such, I assume you are rendering them via javascript.
My assumption would be that the Twitter bot (still called twitterbox, not xbot!) doesn't render javascript, and you'll need to have them generated server-side so that Twitter can see them.
Whilst it's probably worth adding Twitter's own card metatags, their documentation says they are not required fields.

Blazor Interactive Server is weird. It has two initialization passes. In the first pass, it's the raw web page delivered up fast. So no DB access. The second pass reads the DB and populates the page. You are seeing the first pass. I have code in it where, if the User-Agent has the text "bot", "inspection", or "validator" in it, it reads the DB in that first pass. But if not, it doesn't.

My guess is you read the first pass with an app where the User-Agent does not have that text. This matters for Structured Data, but should this matter for Open Graph? Because, the page is fully rendered well before a user clicks the button to text/email the page. Or does it read that initial rendering for later use? TIA

I'm afraid I don't know the answer to that.  If I were you, I'd create a static copy of the final rendered page and see if it works on that.  If it does, it will be the page rendering.

It was using the first pass static HTML. I changed it to always fully render on the first pass and it works. While I have you, is doing the 4 basic meta tags sufficient for all uses if all I care about is the data in those 4? My web site will be used to forward a link to others and so the image and url is all that's needed.

I'd assume it would be fine for most use cases. Perhaps read the documentation on cards to see if you'd think any of the other fields are of value, though.

I recommend you to use meta tags for Twitter:
Twitter Summary Card
On the other hand, take into account that Twitter has a cache for links. Try using meta tags for Twitter and with a different page of your website.

Firstly, Twitter might ignore OpenGraph. They have their own meta tags, which you can check out here.
Secondly, the issue could be server-side caching. A version without the tags might have been cached, which is why they aren't showing up.
Also, I’d recommend checking your robots.txt just in case.
And generally, initialization sometimes takes time, so just give it a bit of patience.
